# Where can I source images for ebooks that are not restricted by reproduction limits nor dpi?

Tags: image, source, dpi

As you are probably aware, most image vendors restrict you to the number of reproductions you can make using their images. Many have additional licenses that you can purchase, but they are often exorbitantly priced (specially if you need to use many images-like myself). They also generally have some form of size restriction such as don't use images over 72dpi.

**Question**

Where can I source images for ebooks that are not restricted by reproduction limits nor restricted to 72 dpi?

**UPDATE**

I don't mind paying for images as long as the prices aren't exorbitant.

*MY OWN RESEARCH*

Flikr allows you to search specifically for content that is ok for commercial use and is licensed under the creative commons licence. http://www.flickr.com/search/advanced/?

Comment: I would assume 36 dpi to be fine if the size (in mm/inch) is big enough? Are you looking at images with some minimum pixel size? And if so what would that be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems I'm misunderstanding dpi somehow? I always assumed the dots were of equal size, but spaced out more in images of lower dpi. I might try to have this clarified in another question. Anyway, I'll try to explain what I'm doing a bit better-I'm using multiple images of multiple sizes. Each image has been set to a density of 300dpi using gimp. My ebooks are targeting the ipad, but I expect a large percentage of users will want to print the books too. I expect 36dpi to be far too small, but perhaps I need to revisit my understanding of dpi.

Comment: This should be two questions - one about dpi and the other about cost

Comment: Seems to be **off-topic** since it's a *"shopping list question"* (similar to [this one](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/188/85)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a shopping list question

Comment: voting in scope per related discusion http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-exactly-makes-a-shopping-list-question-a-shopping-list-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends from the type of images you need, but I'd suggest to have a look at [openclipart](http://openclipart.org/). Its great advantage, besides containing images with an open license, is that they are stored in vectorial format (SVG), so they may be scaled at will.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has many image that are in the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aImage_use_policy) or with [acceptable free licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aImage_copyright_tags/Free_licenses). I would assume that—with proper attribution—you can use images in the public domain, and part of the free license, in your own work.

On this [site](http://www.fotosearch.com/stock-photo-licensing/) you can see the stock-photo-licensing agreements of various suppliers.

I have a—now unused—collection of ArtBeats Imagary IIRC was royalty free after the initial payment (I would have to dig it up from storage to see the actual license that was signed).

Comment: I think you mean [Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) not Wikipedia.  The majority of images are actually on commons.