# How can I validate an epub file?

Tags: epub, creation, validation

How can I formally validate the structure of an `.epub` file and check it for errors?

Comment: Note that a formal validation of the structure is no guarantee that the book works properly on various readers. A good additional step would be to try reading the book in software such as calibre, plus whatever hardware you own yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IDPF, the consortium that promotes the `.epub` standard, has released a tool named epubcheck.
It is available both via an online web-app [here](http://validator.idpf.org/), or as a stand-alone program [here](https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck).

There is also another tool called FlightCrew, available [here](http://code.google.com/p/flightcrew/); this is also integrated within Sigil, a full fledged epub editor (available [here](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/)).

All these tools are free and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have found eBookIt's online validator very good:
http://www.ebookit.com/epub-validator3

[No longer exists at the specified location/URL]

Comment: Isn;'that just a packaging of the idpf validator?